# How, in QML, can I use a JS ArrayBuffer as a ListElement

Tags: javascript, listview, qml

I'd like to store some income hex data, and for memory efficiency purposes would like not to convert it into a hex-escaped string.

```
Item {
    ListModel {
        id: model
    }

    Component.onCompleted: {
        let dummyInputData = "1\\x200\\x00\\x01234567890"
        let byteArray = str2ab(tmpString)


        model.append({"timestamp_utc": 1, "data": dummyInputData});
    }

    // Converts string to 8-bit array buffer. This is used for testing purposes
    function str2ab(str) {
        var buf = new ArrayBuffer(str.length);
        var bufView = new Uint8Array(buf);
        for (var i=0, strLen=str.length; i < strLen; i++) {
            bufView[i] = str.charCodeAt(i);
        }
        return buf;
    }
}
```

The above (seemingly) results in no data being stored in `data`, but also no error.

How would I do this?

Comment: How are you validating your results? The code you've provided doesn't show how you're using the model. It looks like data should just hold the dummyInputData string. Is that what you want? What are you wanting to do with the str2ab function?

Comment: @JarMan the `str2ab()` function transforms a string into a byte array, although it's only here so that it's clear the specific kind of ArrayBuffer I'm looking for. This is a snippet, and I'm not even sure it would work if you copy-pasta'ed it. Validation comes through the debugger, as well as various other commands (e.g. `model.get(0).data`). As near as I can tell, the data is not there.

Comment: If you're on Qt6.4+ have you thought of using `property list<var>` instead of `ListElement`?

Comment: @StephenQuan, thanks for the suggestion. That's basically what I'm doing right now. However, I want to ultimately attach this to a ListView, so the ideal place for this data is in a model.

Comment: @KennSebesta the thing is `list<var>` CAN be attached to a `ListView` just like a `ListModel` can. To illustrate, I've provided examples on how both work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't recommend attempting to store the ArrayBuffer directly into the ListElement in a ListModel. In fact, a lot of non-trivial JavaScript objects cannot be stored either. To cover all those cases, I recommend storing them in a lookup object but linking them back to your ListModel, for example:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
Page {
    ListView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: contacts
        delegate: Frame {
            ColumnLayout {
                TextField { text: uid } // "BGATES"
                TextField { text: gname } // "Bill"
                TextField { text: sname } // "Gates"
                TextField { text: contacts.extras[uid].data instanceof ArrayBuffer } // true
                TextField { text: contacts.extras[uid].data.byteLength } // 23
                TextArea {
                    implicitWidth: 300
                    text: JSON.stringify( contacts.extras[uid], undefined, 2)
                    background: Rectangle {
                        border.color: "#ccc"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ListModel {
        id: contacts
        property var extras: ({ })
    }
    function str2ab(str) {
        var buf = new ArrayBuffer(str.length);
        var bufView = new Uint8Array(buf);
        for (var i=0, strLen=str.length; i < strLen; i++) {
            bufView[i] = str.charCodeAt(i);
        }
        return buf;
    }
    Component.onCompleted: {
        contacts.append({uid:"BGATES", gname:"Bill", sname:"Gates"});
        contacts.extras["BGATES"] = {
            data: str2ab("1\\x200\\x00\\x01234567890"),
            contact: {
                address: "1 Microsoft Way",
                company: "Microsoft",
            },
            hobbies: [ "reading", "wordle" ]
        };
    }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=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)

Alternatively, if you're using Qt6.4+ for such cases, you can consider using `list<var>` instead of `ListModel`:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
Page {
    property list<var> contacts
    ListView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: contacts
        delegate: Frame {
            ColumnLayout {
                TextField { text: modelData.uid } // "BGATES"
                TextField { text: modelData.gname } // "Bill"
                TextField { text: modelData.sname } // "Gates"
                TextField { text: modelData.extra.data instanceof ArrayBuffer } // true
                TextField { text: modelData.extra.data.byteLength } // 23
                TextArea {
                    implicitWidth: 300
                    text: JSON.stringify( modelData.extra, undefined, 2)
                    background: Rectangle {
                        border.color: "#ccc"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    function str2ab(str) {
        var buf = new ArrayBuffer(str.length);
        var bufView = new Uint8Array(buf);
        for (var i=0, strLen=str.length; i < strLen; i++) {
            bufView[i] = str.charCodeAt(i);
        }
        return buf;
    }
    Component.onCompleted: {
        contacts.push( { uid: "BGATES", gname: "Bill", sname: "Gates", extra: {
            data: str2ab("1\\x200\\x00\\x01234567890"),
            contact: {
                address: "1 Microsoft Way",
                company: "Microsoft",
            },
            hobbies: [ "reading", "wordle" ]
        } } );
    }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=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)

Also, in some cases, you can simply declare a large `JavaScript` array, but, the pain point with that is that it will not react to incremental updates. This isn't recommended, because, if you were to use such a thing with a `ListView` every time you updated the array the ListView would reset hence losing any context. `ListModel` and `list<var>` are really better recommendations.